Why are form-control dates broken on iPhone?
For some reason on iPhone the form-control class on the date field breaks the output. This occurs on both Safari and Chrome so is clearly an iPhone issue.



<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>With FC: <input type="date" name="BookingStart" class="form-control w-auto d-inline ms-5"></p>

    <p>Without FC: <input type="date" name="BookingStart" class="w-auto d-inline ms-5"></p>
  </div>
</body>



Is this a bug or is it something I need to change?
